# How to setWithPriority and using Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP to order by timestamp in Zapier

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I am using Zapier firestore trigger to do some tasks. However I am unable to get new records. I cannot find a way to calling setWithPriority and using Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP to order by timestamp.

This is my current structured query

```
{
 "orderBy": [{
         "field": {
                  "fieldPath": "primaryEmail",
                  },
         "direction": "DESCENDING"
    }]
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Best,

Shashi Kiran

Comment: You're using Cloud Firestore, but `setWithPriority` and `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` are both from the Realtime Database API. While both are databases that are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and don't share APIs. If you're using Firestore, there's no way to use the `setWithPriority` and `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` from the Realtime Database API. It'll probably be easier to help you accomplish what you want with Zapier and Firestore if you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, instead of *how* you're trying to accomplish it with these mixed APIs.

Comment: I am using a firestore trigger to add new users to email octopus. I am using Zapier to handle this task. To use firestore trigger, I need to write structured query which I have give above, It works but I always get the message new documents are not found. when I run the task manually. I used ```createTime``` field of firestore with  orderBy to get the latest documents but still I am not getting the new documents.

Comment: The query looks like (I haven't used Zapier with Firestore myself) it should retrieve all documents. Are you saying you only see a subset of the documents? Can you show the results you get (in the question please)? It'd also be useful to see what you  have in Firestore, to see what isn't being returned.